# Why does Laravel only support AES-256-CBC?

Tags: aes, openssl, key-size

[Modern Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption) uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256-CBC encryption along with a MAC. However, I was under the impression that this is not a particularly secure approach.

- Why does Laravel only support AES-256-CBC?

While I'm not using this feature for sensitive data, I'd still like to follow best practices.

Comment: Oddly, the [Encrypter source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php) seems to indicate the default is AES-128-CBC -> `public function __construct($key, $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC')`.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the IV used to encrypt in CBC mode is also the key for the HMAC computation on the ciphertext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two reasons:

- The addition of good libraries/modes is quite recent (Libsodium is only available since 7.2+ and AES-XXX-GCM with 7.1+).
- Encrypted messages in Laravel don't have a version marker that would allow more than one scheme to coexist on a given installation. It mean that a given site must stick with one encryption scheme / key or all the existing encrypted messages will become unreadable. It makes upgrading encryption in Laravel quite hard.

...and since the current scheme (AES-256-CBC + HMAC-256) is fairly competent, Taylor is sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may not be a good answer but also long to be a comment. The following quotes from [LaravelAEAD](https://github.com/hernandev/laravel-aead)

> This package replaces, when installed and enabled, the default encryption implementation of Laravel, which currently supports only two variants of the same block cipher, AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC.
>
> The reason for only having two options is probably based on PHP history itself, like the (not so much) recent depreciation of MCrypt.

and from LaravelAEAD's definition;

> LaravelAEAD is a library which provides Advanced Encryption with Associated Data (AEAD) for Laravel.

[Authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) assure the confidentiality and authenticity of data. In [TLS 1.3](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3) we have GCM and CCM modes, these are current practices.